# Google Play Store is missing FIREBASE Error not storing data in database

Tags: java, android, firebase

Data not storing in firebase database. getting this error on android studio run:
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx6IS.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: What's the problem with the highlighted code?